# Uninstall harmful app. 'Mobile tracker' can damage your device.'

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notifications

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 international i9300 since 2012. I've never rooted it. The last app I've installed was a few months ago. I'm running Android 4.4.4.

Today, for the first time ever, I've gotten this notification. It appeared sometime while I was using the Dolphin browser app.

[XDA forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-3/help/uninstall-harmful-app-mobile-tracker-t3597448) thread seems inconclusive. Some say it's an app that you have to install (obviously I've never installed this app), others say it's a part of Samsungs firmware.

Does anyone know what this might be?

**EDIT:**

Although I haven't been able to confirm this, this *seems* to be an official Android or Google Play notification. I've clicked the uninstall button and the (Samsung's pre-installed) app 'Mobile tracker' has been removed from the applications list.

Comment: Answer: malware, addware and so... Stop browsing on untrusted websites with an untrusted browser. Some websites, those that have free contents are known to be full of malwares. Don't simply install.

Comment: Did the message come with a button to install a package that will "clean" it out for you? I suspect it is clickbait for malware, if you haven't installed anything recently.

Comment: @wbogacz looks like a native notification. The only button available is the "Disable" button.

Comment: Come to think of it. The white triangle with a black question mark is every-so-slightly different from the original Samsung's icon. Hmm... Should I do a factory reset or just change browsers? Is there a virus/malvare/adware checker for Android (that can be easily uninstalled later)?

Comment: Some of those malicious Javascript popups are pretty good in imitating "native screens" – especially on devices as common as that (a screenshot might help, in case you see it again – which doesn't mean you should hunt for it, rather follow the advises given in previous comments). If you didn't interact with it (i.e. pressed any button/link it showed) but "backed out" (back button, power off, whatever to "abort"), no harm should have been done. Forget about any app calling itself "Anti **VIRUS"** – they often introduce more trouble than they solve. …

Comment: … though if you insist, find some here: [Anti-Malware](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_antimalware#group_445) . Make sure to read the previous-to-last bullet point [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/app-modules-1#findings) first, though – then you know what I mean by "introducing trouble". Same for the "introduction" at the top of the app listing.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same notification on my Galaxy S 3 yesterday. It prompted me to uninstall it as the app can be used to spy on me. Here is a picture of the pop up:

[image]

I clicked on the OK button and hope that no malware has infiltrated the phone this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have got S3 i9300, I got this message too. The message was from Google appstore app. I could disable it.  But couldn't remove it.