# I am getting the notification: Disable harmful app. On disabling it, I am still getting back the notification. What do I do?

Tags: google-play-store, notifications

From the past few weeks, I am getting the notification:

> Disable harmful app
>
> "System Notification Service" can damage your device.

On tapping on the notification, I am getting two options:

> Keep Anyway (Unsafe)
>
> Ok

After pressing Ok,  a few minutes later, I am getting back the notification again.

In google play store app, in the play protect section, it has this detail:

> This app can download potentially harmful apps.

My mom too has phone from the same brand; it too has started getting same notification.

Is there a problem? What do I do?

Edit: Model Number: Gionee P5L;
Android Version: 5.1;
Android security patch level: 2017-03-05;
Kernel Version: 3.10.65+;
Build Number: [SW VERSION]
P5L_0301_V5557
[HW VERSION]
P5L_Mainboard_P3;
System Version: amigo3.1

[image]

Comment: We will need more details in order to identify the app you're having trouble with. Did you download it off the Play Store? Can you share a link if that's the case?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I didn't download the app (System Notification  Service) from the playstore. It seems to be a system app, I can only disable or force it to stop.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173926/uninstall-harmful-app-mobile-tracker-can-damage-your-device 
Might just need to reinstall OS (to be safe) and then avoid suspect websites

Comment: @WillW: Have updated the post. Okay, I will see on reinstalling it. From both the phones, common sites visited seems to be that of kodi video pairing sites.

Comment: You really should reinstall android if you're seeing this about a built in app to be safe like @WillW said

Comment: This could be spyware app disguised as a system app. Google is rightly pointing you to uninstall it. But if you are installing this app on another device and you dont want that to show this notification then you can disable it as per this link: http://trackmyphones.com/b/disable-android-app-is-harmful-security-alert/

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the security popup by Settings -> Google -> Security -> (Play Protect) And uncheck “Scan Device for Security threats”

If there are more details under that tab, then comment below.

For safer app installation, you can disable Unknown Sources in Settings -> Security -> Disable "Allow installation of apps from unknown source"

For safer browsing, you can install firefox for Android, and add ublock origin as an adblocker extension when browsing the web.

Comment: I have disabled app installation from unknown sources option, in both the phones. I am using firefox with ublock origin in one of the phone. App seems to be of system's, which can only be disabled.

Comment: The first step can be used if you think the app is a false positive.  Think you can whitelist the notification app.

Comment: How do I know it as false positive? Do I use antivirus or antimalware apps?

Comment: if you fresh installed the OS and still see the message, its probably a false positive. 
I have never had luck with antimalware apps on android, but malwarebytes is great on PC.